# Can I calculate the difference between two dates if there is matching data in another column, MTBF calculation

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to find the mean time between failure of serialized equipment. I am using Access 2013 for my database and have Access 2016 also. My problem is that I have multiple entries for the serial numbers with Warranty start dates and job entry dates. I need to calculate the days between each job if the serial numbers match. Using > to find the dates and then calculate them worked great until I had more than one entry for a serial number.

I have tried using a join property between two tables but could not calculate the dates correctly with more than two entries

Below is my sql statement. I would rather use VBA to calculate this if possible. I can post my data with the criteria I am looking for, this is my first post.

```
SELECT qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed.BarCode, 
    tbl_Closed_Jobs.Cust_Part, 
    tbl_Closed_Jobs.Desc, 
    tbl_Closed_Jobs.Plant, 
    tbl_Closed_Jobs.Date_Ent, 
    qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed.Warranty_Activation,
    qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed.Warr_WO, 
    qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed.Cust_Ref, 
    qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed.Rel_No, 
    (tbl_Closed_Jobs.Date_Ent- 
    [qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed].Warranty_Activation) AS MTBF, 
    "C" AS Status, 
    tbl_Closed_Jobs.Prty
FROM qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Closed_Jobs ON qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed.BarCode = tbl_Closed_Jobs.BarCode
WHERE (((tbl_Closed_Jobs.Date_Ent)>=([qry_MTBF_Warranty_Date_Closed].[Warranty_Activation])) AND ((tbl_Closed_Jobs.Prty) Not Like "1C*"))
ORDER BY tbl_Closed_Jobs.Cust_Part;
```

I expect to only have an output of days where my serial(Barcodes) match and the Priority codes are no a 1C. I can post an Excel file if that would help.

Thanks

So, I have SQL to find the number of days between the two dates if there are only two matching barcodes. I need to know the difference of days between each entry. The below sql will give me the Min and Max days and the difference of them but some barcodes will have multiple entries and I need to know the difference between each entry if the barcodes match..
SELECT t1.BarCode, max(abs(DateDiff("d", t3.Date_,t1.Date_Warranty))) AS DateDifference
FROM tbl_MTBF_Multiple_Entries AS t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.BarCode as BarCode_, Max(t2.Date_Ent) as Date_
    FROM tbl_MTBF_Multiple_Entries t2
    GROUP BY t2.BarCode
    )  AS t3 ON t1.BarCode=t3.Barcode_
WHERE t1.Date_Warranty < t3.Date_
GROUP BY t1.BarCode;

Comment: Welcome to SO. A data sample would be helpful. Please, post your data (input) and your expected output (a sample of what would be a correct result).

Answer (score 0):

Try using built-in vba DateDiff()

```
Function DateDiff(Interval As String, Date1, Date2, [FirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = vbSunday], [FirstWeekOfYear As VbFirstWeekOfYear = vbFirstJan1])
    Member of VBA.DateTime
```

Example:

```
' Return the number of days remaining in the taxation year from the present date.
' Positive value <= 365 = taxation year has # days left.
' Positive value > 365, date is before taxation year.
' Negative value = beyond taxation year
Public Function daysRemainingInTaxYear() As Integer

    Dim myTaxationYear
    Dim myEoY As Variant

    myTaxationYear = DLookup("TaxationYear", "myParametersT", "ID=1")

    myEoY = "31/12/" & myTaxationYear
    daysRemainingInTaxYear = DateDiff("d", Now(), myEoY)
End Function
```